# Weighted average of global population not equal to rolled up local weighted average.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I am not great with notation but will try my best.    Basically I have 3 populations Pop A Pop B and Pop C.

1. Pa + Pb + Pc = Global Population/Treatment
2. Pa + Pb = local population/eligible population 80%
3. Pc = different local population 20%
   There is a variable allocation between PA + PB

Pa is representative of traffic nominally

Pb is representative of traffic when Pa is at 100%

`true Conversion Rate is (1-d) * Pa + d * Pb`

`at d (allocation percentage) of 1, the CVR is the adjusted Pb`

`at d (allocation percentage) of 0, the revenue per click is the adjusted Pa.`

`Therefore the Weighted average of the aggregate is (1-d) * CVRPa + d * CVRPc`

This is at the aggregate level. But there are many rows of data that roll up into the aggregate.  When I try to calculate at the row level instead of the aggregate the values do not add up.  It is the same as the aggregate calculation but then I also adjust for the allocation percentages

`First Calc: (1-d) * CVRPa + d * CVRPc`

`Second Calc: adjusted_cvr=(1-d) * CVRPa + d * CVRPb`

`Final  Roll up by weighted average of each row.`

I believe the variance and difference in the ratios of Pa+Pb:Pc Globally do not align with the ratio of Pa:Pb locally.

Is this the case and if so is there a way to correct for it?